# android: video as background view

Tags: android-video-player

I want to play video in background of the view.In view i want to some other view like button and textview, can it is possible to do that?
 i have try using the following code
 <

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView">
        </VideoView>
<TextView 
    android:text="hi123"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me how can it possible to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have done with your code than please update it. I also need to do this task but I am not able to do from a long time. If you dont mine than please update your way / code over here . thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you can put a videoView in background. 
The better option would be to use a frame layout with a transparent background and put your other views on the top of it.

Comment: thank for help,it is working but i have put the relative layout inside the framelayout then relative layout property not working like below/above etc,is there any way to do it?

Comment: Framelayout must not be an issue when merged with relativelayout. I have used it and it works fine for me. May be you can go through the attributes in your xml file once again to identify the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Shafi is right i m just posting code how i have done,

```
 <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView  
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"

         />.....
```

I hope this code will help some one.
Thank you

Comment: Sameer, how does your java code for the video player look like? Can you share that? I am getting a pop message saying "Cant play the video". Then I get a black screen.