# Setting a video to play as the background in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to make a video run in the background of my application.

I've searched high and low and the closest thing I could find was this other post:
[Integrating video file in android app as app background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830111/integrating-video-file-in-android-app-as-app-background)

The code provided does not work (I get 3 errors in java).

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? I want it to play in the background as I would later like to set a zoom in and out buttons that will allow you to magnify the video playing in the background. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can put a video as a background view. But you can try to use a video view and put it inside Frame layout.

You can use this link for further reference:
[android: video as background view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074600/android-video-as-background-view)

Comment: Will try this within 24 hours and I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't get a video to play in a video view. I tried following some tutorials. No luck so far.

Comment: I believe I found my problem. I was trying to set a path for the video in my actual res/raw folder. I need to first save it to SD card it seems, but I was having a problem because my Galaxy Nexus does not have an SD card and the only file system paths I've seen on android started with SDCARD/Something/Folder/File.extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im using exoplayer to put a video from local:

in xml:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/compensation_video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="fill"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

in activity or fragment:

```
private val exoPlayerTwo by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).build()
}

private fun showBackgroundVideo() {
    //also set to the player view
    binding.compensationVideoView.player = exoPlayerTwo
    exoPlayerTwo.playWhenReady = true
    exoPlayerTwo.volume = 0f
    exoPlayerTwo.repeatMode = SimpleExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ALL // With thi loop the video
    val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.compensalia_background_video)
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
    exoPlayerTwo.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    exoPlayerTwo.prepare()
}
```

also realease the component:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    exoPlayerTwo.release()
}
```